# Undetermined coeficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm reading Tenenbaum book on differential equations. His procedure to solve a second order homogenous equations for a particular case is as follows:

[image]

Then there is the following example:

$$y''+y=\sin 3x+\sin x$$

The complementary function is:

$$y_c=c_1\sin x+c_2\cos x$$

Since $\sin x$ appears in both $Q(x)$ and in $y_c$ we need to multiply by $x$:

$$y_p= Ax\sin x + \ldots$$

And include all it's derivatives that are linearly independent:

$$(x\sin x)'=B\sin x+Cx\cos x$$

We differentiate again because the terms are linearly independent still:

$$(\sin x+x\cos x)'=D\cos x+E\cos x+Fx\sin x=G\cos x+Fx\sin x$$

Summing all the terms and grouping the constants:

$$y_p=A\sin 3x+B\cos 3x+C_1x\sin x + C_2 x\cos x+C_3\sin x+C_4\cos x$$

But on the book the author writes:

$$y_p=A\sin 3x+B\cos 3x+C_1x\sin x + C_2 x\cos x$$

Where are the $\sin x$ and $\cos x$? Where do I failed?

Comment: You may get an answer, but your question doesn't say what $Q(x)$ or $y_c$ and so on are. Without looking at the book I don't know, although someone might. If you don't get any answers to this it might be worth improving the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No error, they are just unnecessary in the particular solution, because they are in the complementary solution.  Your constants $A$, $B$, $C_1$, and $C_2$ will be uniquely determined, but $C_3$ and $C_4$ will be arbitrary (usually in the way undetermined coefficients is taught, the complementary and particular solutions are added together at the end to find the general solution).